# setting style attribute based on browser agent

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem which is breaking my site looks and feel. My header works well in Chrome but breaks in firefox. I fixed it then it worked well firefox and broke in chrome.

I was wondering if there is a way to detect which browser is viewing the site and based on that apply appropriate styling code. I am not good at all in javascript so really appreciate your support.

Code for chrome:

```
          <table id="mini-login" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="margin-top:0px; float:left; margin-left:80px;">
```

Code for Firefox:

```
          <table id="mini-login" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style=" margin-top:-95px; float:left; margin-left:40px;"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid coding in `<tables>`. You can use div for such layouts.

Try `position:relative` and adjust `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` so the same code runs in both the browsers.

Comment: that didn't work because I tried it already. I should really use a div and I agree. But still I need to fix this :(

Comment: Please share the URL, so I could try something with that. You should also use firebug to change layout at runtime.

Comment: it is developed on local unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, then try to avoid `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` and adjust the layout with `CSS`. This may be the possible reason for your layout broke. Just give it a try.

Comment: If you can give a fiddle for the same, that will be better.

Comment: check the questions for snapshots of chrome vs. firefox

Comment: actually changed it to div and did some modifications with margins and now working fine :) Thanks again for support

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), specifically the [load feature](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load), to load resources based on browser capabilities.